# How can I collect SQL commands of an application on server level?

Tags: sql, oracle, profiler, trace

What is the technics if I want to catch/monitor/log/save the native SQL commands of the application developed by us?   We have Oracle database.
I have already tried the SQL Developer/Tools/Monitor session function, but it does not include the SQL statements of our apps. RealTime SQL Monitor function contains only a part of the required commands and a lot of useless entries….

Practically what I want:
-   „Switch On” the trace function (e.g. in SQL developer or SQL*Plus)
-   Launch the application and try some functionalities with real data (e.g. the slow queries)
-   As soon as I think I have enough measurement:   „Switch Off” the trace function   and….
-   Start analyzing/tuning the SQL commands  (e.g. with SQL developer/Explain Plan, etc.)

Comment: This question is to broad for SO, I am voting to close it. There is a whole chapter in the documentation on this topic, see  [8 Performing Application Tracing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL794) in the Performance Tuning Guide. There are examples there how to enable tracing, how to collect and analyze tracing files etc.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can always use awr reports for specified time to know which queries were running in the databases in given time period.

Run awr report using ;

```
@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql
```

AWR captured top sql, but you can increase number of sql captured in awr.

2) Database level trace can capture all sqls run, with execution plans & other stats. You can manually start & stop trace. Once trace is stopped, you can use tkprof to generate readable files. trace always cause bit of performance over head & space overhead , but not massive in my experience.

- Abhi